# My app keeps force closing, and won't install on some devices

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I'm having some issues. So I've been developing a navigation app the last 2 weeks and sent it out to a few people to beta test. Some of them are getting a "Parsing Error" installing the .apk from an email attachment, otheres it installs fine and runs flawlessly, and others the app will force close randomly. What is the issue?

I developed the app with the jquery mobile framework and the latest version of phonegap, along with a jquery mobile plugin for google maps. I don't think it's my html5 markup that's causing problems with the app, I think it might be something up with my manifest file?

Also, if it makes any difference, whenever I run the app with the virtual emulator, I'm getting a OpenGL or something like that error saying, could not load the vertex shader.

Here is a copy of my manifest file, and the source file for my app..

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.slammednavigator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
    />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"     />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SlammedNavigatorActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my source file for phonegap that initializes and runs the html5 portion in assets/www

```
package com.slammednavigator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class SlammedNavigatorActivity extends DroidGap {
private PowerManager.WakeLock wLock;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "SN Wake Lock");
    wLock.acquire();

}

public void onDestroy() {
    wLock.release();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you found out what version of Android this is failing on, and the manufacturer/model of devices that are throwing an error?

Comment: One of the phones it's failing on is my friend's droid x running android version: 2.3.4

Comment: Right, and on all of the ones it is okay, is that a different version? Put another way: is the version number relevant? Also: can you grab some demo Phonegap code from the internet, and install that on a failing device? If so, what is the difference between that and your own code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the .apk file is not successfully install in device then it gives this type of error.

as per your saying in some device your application run fluently and in some it gives forse close and parsing error , it means in some device application install successfully and in remaining it was not install perfectly.